# Counting rows that had a previous event with a condition in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a big query table which looks like this:

```
event_date      event_timestamp         event_name                       user_pseudo_id
20210207        1612690020556013        purchase_trial_activated         abc
20210207        1612694989097000        purchase_completed               abc
20210207        1612694989097000        purchase_completed               def
```

I have an event `purchase_trial_activated` and `purchase_completed`. I am trying to count the purchase / trial ratio. The problem is not all purchases had a trial. The column `user_pseudo_id` can be used to check if a user had an `purchase_trial_activated` event, if he did have it and had `purchase_completed` event it means he purchased after trial. `def` `pseudo_user_id` does not have an event `purchase_trial_activated` meaning he did not used the trial. I am only interested in users that took the trial.

I used:

```
select 
    geo.country as country, platform, event_date,  
    sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'session_start' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS `session_start`,
    sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'purchase_preview_page' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS `purchase_preview_page`,
    sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'purchase_trial_activated' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS `purchase_trial_activated`,
    sum(CASE WHEN event_name like 'purchase_completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0  end) AS `purchase_completed`
from 
    `project.dataset.*`
where 
    event_date > '20200101'
group by 
    event_date, country, platform;
```

Which returns

```
country         platform    event_date  session_start   purchase_preview_page   purchase_trial_activated    purchase_completed
United States   ANDROID     20210122    2871            3                       0                           7
China           IOS         20210208    3611            1054                    84                          43
Poland          ANDROID     20210208    722             0                       0                           0
Estonia         WEB         20210208    32              0                       0                           0
```

But in this case I am counting all `purchase_completed` events when I only want to count those `purchase_completed` events, who had `purchase_trial_activated` for the same `pseudo_user_id`.

So `pseudo_user_id` `abc` had both events, meaning I will count his purchase, but `def` has only `purchased_completed` event and not `purchase_trial_activated` meaning I will not take his purchase in to account.

How can I achieve such a result?

Comment: Those what?  Can you fix your data so it is readable?

Comment: Updated the question and the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate twice.  Once to user level, where you can ascertain if that user had a trial or not, completed a purchase of note, etc. Then aggregate again to your final results.

```
WITH
  user_summary
AS
(
  SELECT
    geo.country as country,
    platform,
    event_date,
    pseudo_user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN event_name = 'session_start'            THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)   AS `has_session_start`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN event_name = 'purchase_preview_page'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)   AS `has_purchase_preview_page`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN event_name = 'purchase_trial_activated' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)   AS `has_purchase_trial_activated`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN event_name = 'purchase_completed'       THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)   AS `has_purchase_completed`
  FROM
    `project.dataset.*`
  WHERE
    event_date > '20200101'
  GROUP BY
    geo.country,
    platform,
    event_date,
    pseudo_user_id
)
SELECT
  country,
  platform,
  event_date,
  SUM(has_session_start)                                      AS count_session_start,
  SUM(has_purchase_preview_page)                              AS count_purchase_preview_page,
  SUM(has_purchase_trial_activated)                           AS count_purchase_trial_activated,
  SUM(has_purchase_completed)                                 AS count_purchase_completed,
  SUM(has_purchase_trial_activated * has_purchase_completed)  AS count_trial_activated_and_purchased
FROM
  user_summary
GROUP BY
  country,
  platform,
  event_date
```

Comment: Thank you. I've compared your query and mine, the old one has more session_start, purchase_preview page events than your variant. I image these would not change since there is no difference in how I count the sessions. The only difference is you changed `SUM` to `MAX`.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Yes, I used `MAX()` to get a 1 or 0 on a per user basis.  Such that the last column now tells you "number of USERS that started at least one trial AND complete at least one purchase".  If you need something different, change the aggregation functions to suit your needs.  Just be careful of things like `1 trial and 2 purchases` for a single user.  To give code to cope with that, you need to update your question with enough example data to cover all scenarios you want to cater for, and then show the results you want for those scenarios.